# What are the commands to change value to msgmnb?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, chmod

I've tried `cd /proc/sys/kernel` followed by `sudo chmod u=rwx msgmnb` to get permissions for changing the value but I didn't get them, how can I do it?

Comment: Could you expand on what you're waiting to achieve here ?  Want to increase the message queue as a non-root user?

Comment: I'm making an application used exclusively by me, as for root or non root it's indifferent for me, the main thing is that i want to increase message queue so that this program can use more space on it @steve

Comment: @ZenoRaiser, what are the permissions for `/proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb` on your system? `ls -l /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb`?

Comment: @ilkkachu permissions: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 gen 20 13:46 /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `proc` file system doesn’t support permission changes in `/proc/sys` (thanks to ilkkachu for the correction). Any attempt to change a file’s mode (which is what `chmod` does) is rejected with an “operation not permitted” error.

To change a value, you need to write the file as `root`:

```
echo newvalue | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb
```

or, if you’re `root`:

```
echo newvalue > /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb
```

You can also use `sysctl`:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.msgmnb=newvalue
```

You can ensure your setting is applied at boot by adding it to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: Actually, you can, for some files at least. `chmod 400 /proc/uptime` works fine. chmodding the files under `/proc/sys` doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: Thanks, but my main question is can i change msgmnb value? If yes how?

Comment: Used the last command and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change permissions in `/proc` (at least not with `chmod`).

Comment: Actually, you can, at least for some files

Answer (score 0):

On my system, (almost) everything in `/proc/sys/` already has write access for root. They're also the actual interface to the knobs used by `sysctl`, so they need to be writable. So, no need to `chmod`, just set new values. Either:

```
sysctl kernel.msgmnb=$somevalue
```

or

```
echo $somevalue > /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb
```